Capacitive proximity sensor - Working principle
I'm looking at the working principle for capacitive proximity sensors, when I read online I seem to get conflicting info.
I know that an oscillator is used to generate an AC current, and this is fed into a capacitor plate (electrode of some kind).
Where I am confused is that some sources seem to suggest that the object being detected works as the second plate to the capacitor, and others suggest that there are 2 plates in the detection device.
But this raises some questions.
Scenario 1
If the detected object is the second plate, how is the circuit completed? Perhaps via a connection between the object and "earth ground" which is connected to ground on the device. But then, what if the device is battery powered and not attached to the same "earth ground" as the object? Also I'd expect the connection to earth ground that doesn't go via a wire to be very "unstable" in terms of capacitance as other objects in that path would have an effect (e.g if the object is floating in the air, of if something is inside the ground with capacitance properties), and it wouldn't be very useful for measuring the distance of the object from the plate.
Scenario 2
If there is a "full circuit" built into the device with 2 plates (actual plates as part of the detector device), as this answer seems to suggest.
capacitive proximity sensor - how does it work
Then would that mean that the plates need to be arranged so that the object physically is between them (to act as a dialectic rather than a plate), or is this not a requirement somehow?

There is always a complete circuit. If it doesn't appear that there are enough explicit capacitors around, then you can be sure the circuit is completed by some implicit stray capacitances, which will always exist.
You can run a capacitive sensor in several different modes, which could explain your confusion if you are expecting all sources to say the same thing. Some use an effectively grounded body electrode (finger) to reduce the coupling between two laterally disposed plates, some do the same with stacked plates. Some use an isolated moving plate to increase coupling. Any change of conductor geometry around a number of driven conductors will cause some change in capacitive effects, and there are ICs and associated software to measure all of them. It gets more complicated when the software uses extra guard electrodes around the sense electrodes to try to detect water splashes. Make sure you're reading the tutorial for the exact arrangement of electrodes you're seeing.

https://www.motioncontroltips.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Cap-Prox-Sensor.jpg
So in this example, the dielectric is the yellow bit and the two blue bits at the top (the small bit and the big bit) on either sides of the yellow form a capacitor? And then anything close will interfere with the field between them somehow? But in that case what is the purpose of the shield, surely we don't want it shielded, if we want the object to "modify" that dielectric property of the yellow part?

@OceanExplorer just looks like a rubbish diagram drawn by an artist to me, it's not been drawn to educate engineers.

Is there a better diagram somewhere that shows internals of sensor?

@OceanExplorer look for application notes from the manufacturers of ICs that incorporate capacitive sensing electronics in their products - many MCUs do. They will have good implementation diagrams.

There are a number of ways to make a capacitive sensor. Measuring distance (as opposed to simply detecting presence of an appendage of a bag-of-mostly-water) requires a more controlled situation.
For example, there are sensors that resemble a parallel plate capacitor with the plate spacing changing. Or with the overlap of the plates changing (like an old-school variable air capacitor).
Or you can have a small electrode with an actively driven guard around it moving relative to a plate. Or you can have three electrodes with the center one moving either to change the spacing or to change overlap ('floating vane').
It all depends on the application which is optimal.
See, for example, Capacitive Sensors by Baxter  IEEE press
The ubiquitous digital calipers use a capacitive sensing technique.
